# How do you create an arc for text without distorting in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, text, text-wrap

Good day, I am currently creating a circular logo in Adobe Illustrator CC, what I did in the upper part is making a circle and inserting text using a type on a path tool. My concern is in the lower part of the design. How do you arc it so that it is aligned in the bottom without distorting the text? Any help would be wonderful, thank you for reading this.

[image: my logo]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Draw another Circle (or copy your existing one) and put the bottom type on a path as well.

[image]

You can use `Type > Type On a Path > Type on a Path Options` in the Menu to "flip" the type so it reads either right side up or upside down.